# Best way to stage website with storage

Tags: html, database, web

I am doing a bit of preliminary research before designing a webpage that will ultimately function as a log book for information (something like a linked list).

I would like to have this information stored somewhere online (like my github account etc) so that if I want scale my application and move to mobile apps, I will be able to draw from and manipulate the same set of data.

Is anyone familiar with doing something like this? Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Most common way is to use some sort of database. Are you trying to avoid using a database on your server? Or looking for something free? Or offline? A few more details would be helpful.

Comment: I would like to use something free and online. Would I want to set up a server to store my data to?

Comment: A webserver is a good solution. There are also services that specialize in hosting your data. Amazon has [database products](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/serverless/?hp=r) that might work and will only charge for usage. [Contentful](https://www.contentful.com/) is a place to host site data that gives you a good editor interface into that data. It even has a [free option](https://www.contentful.com/pricing/). There are __lots__ of particular ways to solve your problem, so it's hard to recommend something without knowing a little more about what you're trying to do.